# Incorrect Value Being Retrieved from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Situation: I created a cron job. It was to add orders entered by customers to an API. I set it to run after every one minute.

Problem: Sometimes, when there were too many pending orders, second cron job was being called before first one gets ended. It was resulting in duplicate orders sent through API.

Solution: I created a table named as cron_jobs in my database. It has two columns, ID and status. When a cron job runs, it checks whether the status is 0 or not. If status is 0, it updates the status as 1. It completes its process and marks the status again as 0. If the status of a job is 1 (it means it is already running), and it is hit again, the operation is terminated.

Unexpected Trouble: This solution seems logically correct. But when I implemented it, the results were shocking. When a job is run, its status is updated. But when it is invoked again, database still returns status 0 and it keeps on executing. I have also used sleep method so that I have enough time to investigate the issue. But the database always returns incorrect value than what I can see using phpmyadmin.

Please do no think that I might have committed some stupid mistakes. **Second instance of a file is always fetching incorrect value before the first instance is completely invoked.**
Have a look at my code:

```
<?php
$Output = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select status from jobs where ID='1'"));
if($Output['status'] == '0')
{
    mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("update jobs set status='1' where ID = '1'"));
    mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("update jobs set invoked = invoked+1 where ID = '1'"));
    echo 'Executed';
}
else
{
    echo 'Error: Another cron job already in process. Operation terminated!';
    die();
}

/*I perform some lengthy tasks here*/

    /*Sleep function called to check whether another instance of the program works while this one is in progress */
    sleep(60);

    /*Task is complete. We are marking 0 as status so that another instance is allowed to work on.*/

    mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("update jobs set status='0' where ID = '1'"));
?>
```

**Observation 1**: It works perfectly if I run the second instance in another browser or another computer.

**Observation 2**: I tried to investigate whether it is ACTUALLY being called several times or not. I made another column in the table as "No_Of_Times_Invoked". And I found that the code actually failed when I used from the same browser.

Comment: Could you post your table scheme for `jobs`? Then I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: 1 ID int(11)  2 status int(11)  3 invoked int(11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` query uses the table `cron_jobs`. Every other query uses `jobs`. I believe your `SELECT` query fails, causing `mysql_query()` to return `false`.

```
$Output = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select status from cron_jobs where ID='1'"));
```

Because `mysql_query()` returns `false` here, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` also returns `false`.

```
if($Output['status'] == '0')
```

`$Output` is `false`. In PHP, when using `==`, type conversion can take place. In this case, `$Output['status'] == '0'` evaluates to `true`. (Note that `$Output['status']` is `null`, but `null == '0'` evaluates to `false`. The joys of [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [loose comparisons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).)

Replace your query with

```
SELECT `status` FROM jobs WHERE ID = '1'
```

and it should run OK.

I do recommend to add some more error checking to the return values of the `mysql_*()` functions (use `$returnValue === false`) or, even better, to switch to [PDO](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

---

**Updated after some discussion in the comments**

It seems the problem is that you're testing from a browser. At least Firefox 23.0.1 (which I used for testing) does not send the second request until the first request is complete. This would explain all behavior you're seeing. A new browser or computer would not be able to re-use the connection so in that case it works.

If I launch the script from the command line twice (five seconds apart), it works correctly: the second run outputs `Error: Another cron job already in process. Operation terminated!`.

Note that PHP does complain about the invalid `mysql_fetch_assoc()` you have around each `mysql_query("update ...")` function call:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /test/test.php on line 7

Comment: That was just a typography mistake. There is no syntactical error in the original program. If I terminate execution of the program then check the value, it returns correct value. It keeps on returning obsolete value until the execution gets completed. I am wondering why.

Comment: I found another thing. It works perfectly if I open 2nd instance in another browser. But if I open all the instances in the same browser, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see any bugs in the code now that you've corrected the typo. I am missing the same thing as you or the error is not in the code you have shown here.

Comment: Tomas, if it had errors, how it could worked perfectly in different browsers?

Comment: It should either always work, or should never work. Why is is working in some specific conditions :( The code is not too long which could have bulk of mistakes. Only a few lines that are in front of you. Try it once, I hope that you'll face the same trouble.

Comment: 1 ID int(11) 
2 status int(11) 
3 invoked int(11)

Comment: I am not sure whether I got your point. Do you mean to say that the connection can't be used to resend request to the same file via one browser? I have traced that functions were being invoked all the times I was calling the file.

Comment: It appears to me that at least Firefox wants to re-use the same connection to request the file. Using the new network inspector (ctrl-shift-q) in Firefox I can see that the second request for the file only gets sent when the first one has received an answer. I see the same thing in my Apache access_log: the second request only appears after the first is served. When I call the script manually two times from the command line, it works exactly as you would expect.